# What is this fake pseudo element in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

I have a firefox related question. 
I frequently see some kind of pseudo elements in Firefox, represented in the debugger by a rectangle with a dot inside :

[image: pseudo element]

In this case, I don't see any valid reason that could explain one pseudo element in the middle of a list.

As always, when I select this kind of element in the debugger, I can not see any css rule applied to it. 
When I look in the previous and next element, I see no rule that could explain the presence of something around.
When I hover it in the debugger, it appears as an element of 3x18 px :

[image: pseudo element size]

I don't see any reason for this element to be displayed here. 
I have a lot of them in the firefox inspector, each one seems to have its own size or rule.

As you can see in the screenshot below, this element does not appears in chromium :

[image: chromium]

What is this symbol ? 
I don't get where it comes from and it looks firefox specific.

Thanks

Update 1 : 
As you can see, it does not seems it comes from my code as I just opened the debugger on stackoverflow and found an other example right here :

[image: stackoverflow example]

Comment: I am pretty sure a strange invisible character. Can you share your code?

Comment: This only happens in Firefox? No other browsers do this for that code?

Comment: Hello @j08691@Temani_Afif It only show up in firefox (developer edition but also standard). I added an example from stackoverflow : just opened the debugger, scrolled a little bit and found an other example. You can see the screenshot uploaded in the post

Comment: Do you have any add-ons in Firefox? Have you tried disabling them?

Comment: The problem still occurs when I disable the extensions. Do you reproduce it on firefox ? Also I'm on debian 9

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). **Screenshots are not sufficient**.

Comment: @Paulie_D As I said upper, I did not found why these characters shows up. I don't have any reproducible example. That's why I posted a screenshot of stackoverflow with the debugger tools open : you can see what I'm talking about here, in the same page. Isn't it enough ? What more can I do if I can't reproduce it clearly but if I give you a live example ? Put the stackoverflow source code page in a snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer by myself.

For some reason that are explained in this [mozilla blog post](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2016/10/17/devtools-now-display-white-space-text-nodes-in-the-dom-inspector/), the Mozilla team decided to identify the white spaces with a special character in the debugger. It seems the whitespaces that anyone can include in its own code (with a new line or a space to have a nice looking code) can have an effect on the rendering sometimes. This is why this character is shown in the debugger.